# How to show single dot if there is only one value in scatter plot using core plot

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I am using scatter plot to draw the graph and it is working fine when data source array count is greater then one.

But when data source array count is 1 then it is not showing anything. My requirement is to show a dot when data count is 1.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you configured scatter plot with a plotSymbol ?

Comment: @azimov I have tried adding plotSymbol but requirement is it should show straight line with out circle.

Comment: at least it displays the dot ?

Comment: @azimov Yes it will display the dot but that is not my requirement. The line should be straight without circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two points to draw a line. When the plot only has one point, set the plot symbol to draw a symbol at that point. When there is more than one data point, set the plot symbol to `nil`. You can change this setting any time the plot data changes and don't have to recreate the whole plot to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We can show dot but how to manage the legends there also it is showing as line with circle.

Comment: Set the line style to `nil` to remove the line.